# List index out of bounds: 1

Tags: salesforce

I have created a VF page with 2 button 1 for add inputtext 1 by 1 and 2nd to delete inputtext 1 by 1.
The process is working 1 am bale to add and delete. But when it came to last inputtext it through's an error. For eg: If added 3 inputtext 1,2,3 
I am able to delete 3,2 but when i delete 1st when it through's an error 
List index out of bounds: 1

here is my code

public PageReference cancel() {

```
system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ eqLstNew Out ' + eqLstNew.size());
integer i =0;
  if( i<eqLstNew.size()){
    i++;
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ eqLstNew 1st ' + eqLstNew.size());
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ i size ' + i);
    eqLstNew.remove(i);

  }
  return null;
}
```

can anybody find the solution and tell me what is wrong in the code.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `i++` call at the end of the `if`:

```
public PageReference cancel() {
system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ eqLstNew Out ' + eqLstNew.size());
integer i =0;
  if( i<eqLstNew.size()){
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ eqLstNew 1st ' + eqLstNew.size());
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ i size ' + i);
    eqLstNew.remove(i);
    i++;
  }
  return null;
}
```

But I don't understand why you are using a variable for this. If you always want to return the first element you should write it like this. Using an extra variable (which always has the same value) makes it more complicated.

```
public PageReference cancel() {
  if(eqLstNew.size() > 0){
    eqLstNew.remove(0);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't why i made it so complicated. But any way it is working, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Wait, wasn't there a loop there before? Or did I just read "if( i<eqLstNew.size()) { i++;" too fast and assume that to be the case? :) Either way, deleting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The first element in the list is at index 0, not index 1. It works when there is more than 1 element because you are actually removing the second element in the list when you do list.remove(1). You should be doing list.remove(0) instead if you want to remove the first element.